# angular ng-click in button in ie9

Tags: angularjs

The `ng-click` directive in a button only works in ie9 when developer console is opened.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" 
        data-ng-click="go('/Edit')">Edit</button>
```

This works in other browsers but in ie9 doesn't call the `go` function unless I open the developer console.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a `console.log` somewhere in that function? At least older versions of IE have a habit of only defining `console` when the console is open, and without that definition you'll get a reference error, which is conveniently hidden by the fact that the console isn't open.

Comment: There was a `console.log` but I removed it before posting the question.  It didn't make it work.

Comment: This fixed my problem.  I added 
if(window.console==null) { 
window.console = {}; 
window.console.log = function(){};
}